# Examination program planning using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to create a program via MATLAB.

As all examination programs we have three things; the start time of the exam, the day of the program and which exam will start at that day and hour. We show this in an array with three variables.

```
hour = [1 2 3];
```

The times are showing up as code, for example, '1' referred to a hour of start of exam it can be 8am to 10am. For '2' maybe 10 to 12 and 3 may be 15 to 17.
and we day array. It's referred to holding range of the examination program. I have chosen 14 days.

```
day = [1...14];
```

Another field is course code, these are referred to courses code. For example code '1' is 'Math' and...

```
Course = [1 … 42];
```

I want a possible combination of day and hour and course, so that when one courses is chosen in a day and hour, it does not repeat in the same day and hour. Also, after one course or one day has filled up, do not use them again, spread courses randomly like this:

```
Hour        1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3  ... 1   2   3
Day         1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4  ... 14  14  14
Course      11  33  12  42  10  1   2   3   9   19  7   40 ... 17   8  3
```

Comment: Just to clarify: There are no constraints other than each hour/day is unique? It is just a matter of making a random link between an hour/day identifier and a course identifier? This is probably a one-liner in Matlab, using 2 or 3 built-in functions. Is it possible to explain where you are stuck?

Comment: What about using [`randperm(course)`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html)? That should solve the problem, or am I missing something?

Comment: @NeilSlater : hi, i think it is well enough clearly friend. i just want that final array without repeat and accident. course is randomizly and day and hour is as well as i said at up.

Comment: @hbaderts yes course is randomizly but hour and day must be sorted

Comment: then @hbaderts has already answered it. case closed! y not use `repmat`?

Comment: @sajadkhammar: Yes the problem is clearly explained, but it is not clear why you could not do it yourself. If you could explain *exactly* where you are stuck, instead of just show the problem, then an answer could explain more, and you would learn more than just the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following code (thanks for @hbaderts suggestion).

```
schedule(3,:) = randperm(12); % randomize 12 courses
schedule(1,:) = repelem([1 2 3 4],3); % repeat 4 days
schedule(2,:) = repmat([1 2 3],1,4); % repeat time slots in each day
```

Output:

```
 1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3     4     4     4
 1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
 5     2     6     4     9     8    12    11     7     1    10     3
```

Comment: thanks friend thankssssss. i have a problem to execute, Undefined function 'repelem' for input arguments of type 'double'. my matlab is 2012 version.  i will update my matlab to 2015 to use repelem. i have another quation. you know for a standard planing we must can start more than one  exam in one day and one hour. for example we can start course 1 in day '1' and in hour '1' also we can start another exam as course'2' in day '1' and hour'1' in same day. can you please solve this problem too? many thanks my good friend :)

Comment: @sajadkhammar, as many others suggested you in previous comments, now pls try based on these given inputs. We all spend our time here with our other schedules. Best gratitude you can give us is to try and ask with your problems/errors :-).